# Runtime complexity of a for loop

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, structure

I am new to Data Structures and Algorithms.

```
for (int i=0; i<p; i++) {

   // Statement
}
```

This loop have 3 steps. Initializing, comparing and incrementing. Will this be 3n?

Comment: `for` loop is not a data structure, it is a statement, i.e. a control structure.

Comment: No, you don't initialize every time and you do an initial condition check before entering the loop to do `p` loops.

Comment: If you are talking about complexity, it will be linear (i.e. O(n)) since it will take p iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization is performed only once at the start of loop. Comparison and increment is performed in each iteration. In this case there will be p iterations so complexity will be constant ie p or in other words O(n)

Comment: Saying O(n) really depends on what is happening inside the loop and what you consider n